# Error in pagination when going on next page

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5.4

I am working on a project with pagination in it. When a user try to search records it will be shown using pagination. Records on first page are shown perfectly without any error but when I go to next page it gives me error

```
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 No message
```

Can anyone please help me to sort this problem. I am sharing my code below.

Controller:

```
  public function index(Request $request)
 {
     $hospitals = DB::table('hospitals')
    ->where('city',$request->city)
    ->paginate(6);
return View::make('/patientPanel/patientHospitalList')->with('hospitals',$hospitals);
 }
```

Route:

```
 Route::post('patientPanel/patientHospitalList',
 'patientHospitalListController@index')->name('hospitalList');
```

View from where city is selected:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('hospitalList')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control" name="city">
                               <option value="lahore">Lahore</option>
                                    <option value="Faislabad">Faislabad</option>
                                    <option value="karachi">Karachi</option>
                                    <option value="islamabad">Islamabad</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 50px; margin-left: 250px;">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </form>
```

And the view where records are shown

```
   <section id="team">

      @include('/patientPanel/load')
  </section>
```

Please tell me how to solve this probelm so that when user goes no next page records will be shown.

Comment: Can you show the code of `/patientPanel/load`

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be using the "get" method:

```
Route::get('patientPanel/patientHospitalList',
 'patientHospitalListController@index')->name('hospitalList');
```

You'll need to change the method on your form to "get" as well.

Comment: I have used get and now i dont get any record at my page 2